# \textcolor in chemfig forces molecule to center?

Tags: chemfig

Why is `\textcolor` forcing my methyl group to center. I don´t want it to do that and so far I could not find anything to counteract this. Does anyone have any sugestions? Thanks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{*6((=O)-N(-\textcolor{red}{CH_3})-*5(-N=-N(-\textcolor{red}{CH_3})-=)--(=O)-N(-\textcolor{red}{H_3C})-)}
\chemfig{*6((=O)-N(-CH_3)-*5(-N=-N(-CH_3)-=)--(=O)-N(-H_3C)-)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to colour *each* atom, enclose the group within braces and separate the groups with a `|`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{*6((=O)-N(-{\color{red}C}|{\color{red}H_3})-*5(-N=-N(-{\color{red}C}|{\color{red}H_3})-=)--(=O)-N(-{\color{red}H_3}|{\color{red}C})-)}

\end{document}
```

[image]